# spring - override spring.profiles.active with @ActiveProfiles

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Each of my tests is annotated with

```
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
```

The content of `application-test.properties` starts with `spring.profiles.active=..`. If this is set to `testdev`, it will override properties by matching properties found in `application-testdev.properties` and analogously if set to `testuat`, it will override with `application-testuat.properties`.

Some of the tests however really only make sense if `testuat` is set, so I annotated them additionally with `@ActiveProfiles("testuat")`. When I run it with `spring.profiles.active=testdev` set in `application-test.properties` it actually seems to ignore the `testuat` properties and only read the base properties and the `testdev` properties.

Is there a way to override `spring.active.profiles` with `@ActiveProfiles` ?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Do you change `spring.profiles.active=` manually to run tests for each environment?

Comment: yes i am currently setting that manually

Comment: Maybe you could use `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE ` environment variable instead of setting it in the file. Then set it on your tests and create the necessary properties files.

Answer (score 2):

By default the `@ActiveProfiles` takes precedence over the `spring.actives.profiles` setting, however you can implement your own `ActiveProfilesResolver` with more flexible behavior. Below is an example implementation that defaults to `test` and optionally adds a second profile if set as a System property.

Replace `@ActiveProfiles("testuat")` with `@ActiveProfiles(resolver = SpringActiveProfilesResolver.class)`

And add this class somewhere in your test codebase:

```
public class SpringActiveProfilesResolver implements ActiveProfilesResolver {
    @Override
    public String[] resolve(Class<?> aClass) {
        List<String> springProfiles = Lists.newArrayList("test");
        String systemSpringProfile = System.getProperty("spring.profiles.active");
        if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(systemSpringProfile)) {
            springProfiles.add(systemSpringProfile);
        }
        return springProfiles.toArray(String[]::new);
    }
}
```

Comment: i would love to see @IncludeProfiles annotation out of the box )